# Gatsby + Bootstrap CSS Issue (Not allowed to request resource)

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, gatsby, react-bootstrap

I have the npm package bootstrap installed + Imported it to the gatsby-browser.js file (See below). The Bootstrap CSS works, but the issue is that I keep getting this error message in the console. What am I doing wrong?

**Possible Issues:**

- Do I need to install react-bootstrap?
- Another Gatsby plugin?
- Am I missing additional Gatsby setup?

**Error:**

```
[Error] Not allowed to load local resource: blob://nullhttp//localhost:8000/bootstrap.min.css.map
[Error] Not allowed to request resource
[Error] Cannot load blob://nullhttp//localhost:8000/bootstrap.min.css.map due to access control checks.
```

**gatsby-browser.js:**

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

**package.json:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "britecharts-react": "^0.5.4",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.1",
    "gatsby": "^2.23.7",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^2.3.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.4.12",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.9.0",
    "react-countup": "^4.3.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0"
  },
```

Comment: I've got the same issue.  Same error message, same `gatsby-browser.js`.  I'm using `    "react-bootstrap": "^1.1.1",`

Comment: I just tried updating to react-bootstrap1.2.2 and I'm still getting the same error in the console.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it turns out the problem comes from the line:

```
"bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
```

...which I also have as a recommended dependency of `react-bootstrap`.  Note that one option would be to [include bootstrap CSS via a CDN link](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#css) instead, as suggested in the `react-bootstrap` [doc](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#css). That way one could remove bootstrap from the project dependencies altogether which would fix this problem.

I decided to persevere and try to fix the issue.

That module has a file `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` which includes a source map directive `sourceMappingURL` right at the end of the file that doesn't work when deployed as a node dependency for my project.

I manually removed that line, and found web pack goes ahead and produces a correct source map value for bootstrap, via base64 encoded data URI's. Problem solved.

You can remove the line via the following sed command (this works on Mac from the root dir of the project):

```
sed -i '' -e '/\/\*# sourceMappingURL.*/d' node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Credit for that one-liner goes to [a post I found](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1341#issuecomment-270261498) discussing removal of source map files, where folks were doing that as part of post build.

I don't plan to rebuild the `bootstrap` package so I don't think post build helps me. Removing it once is fine.

The only issue of course is when I next update that package and my edits to that file are clobbered.  For now I have just added a reminder to myself in my project README to run the `sed` command again when I update packages.

This didn't fix my CSS problems as it happened - they were caused by other issues: in my case it was a number of other CSS files from a starter project that was interfering with the bootstrap CSS, plus also an extra `div` element that I'd used to wrap some nav components which was stopping them rendering properly.